# want to manage user and admin through zfcuser module separately

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am new with zf2 & zfcuser module.
I want to manage separately user & admin through diffrent tables(user,admin) with zfcuser module.
I have made a copy of the zfcuser module for admin & made changes according to new mobule like rename classes, files etc. admin module is exist in the Moudle folder.
It's working fine I mean running without any error, but problem is that both modules are using single table(user) and session.

Please let me know where am I wrong?

I want to use separate authentication for both user and admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want a separate auth system? you are just duplicating code. do you have a good reason for doing this?

Comment: currently when I am login through front-end automatically loged-in from back-end. I want separate login system for user and admin both.

Comment: You could use a single authentication system but use Zend ACL to decide what privileges a user has, a much better solution.

Comment: actually, I want to manage both modules(user & admin) separately (as I mentioned before), because in future many customization will be in both modules & I don't want to authentication dependency on each other modules. I want separate table, files for both.

Comment: you can still use separate tables without duplicating the code though..

Comment: can you show me some example code? please
Thanks